# Dot "." in option value foobars save options function

Tags: theme-development

My theme options save routine is below. I'm finding that if the $value['id'] being passed from my options array has a period in it, the data does not get passed and the options appear to break at that point. Should I opt for another character or is there a workaround for using the period character in an option name?

For example, this works fine:

```
 "id" => "myTheme_color|sidebar",
```

but this does not (no data is passed for the value):

```
 "id" => "myTheme_color.sidebar",
```

The save function is:

```
function mytheme_add_admin(){
global $themename, $shortname, $options; 
if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) )
{
    if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) 
    {
        foreach ($options as $value) 
        {
            update_option( $value['id'], stripslashes($_REQUEST[$value['id']]) ); 
        }
        foreach ($options as $value) 
        {
            if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) 
            {
                update_option( $value['id'], stripslashes($_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ])  ); 
            echo $value['id'].": ".$_REQUEST[$value['id']]."<br>";
            echo $value['id'].": ".stripslashes($_REQUEST[$value['id']])."<br>";
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing two times the same thing (2xforeach) and the previous variant might just overwrite the option if the not set in $_REQUEST. Probably this is the issue?

Comment: Not sure why I had that there, but I've removed it and it does no good. Apparently you can't use periods in options names when using a for loop on the options array at save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dots and spaces are [replaced](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php#72572) by PHP for array indexes via POST and GET. That may cause your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue is here, this test code works fine for me:

```
$options = array( 'test_option' => array('id' => 'myTheme_color.sidebar') );
$test = 'test';
var_dump($options);
foreach ($options as $value) {
    var_dump($value['id']);
    update_option( $value['id'], $test );
}
```

From quick look at source code the most likely point for `update_option` to fail is if SQL query to insert it fails.

My suggestions are to run `$wpdb->print_error()` after operation to check for failed query and hook into `update_option_{$option}` and `updated_option` actions to see if they are firing ([source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L523)).

Comment: And if you have not done it, add `define('WP_DEBUG', TRUE); on the testbed. This might reveal more information with $wpdb as well.